# mongodb error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: mongodb, mysql-error-1067

mongodb error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly

Method 1: Fix Permission Issues. If permission issues are responsible for SQL server error code 1067, then access to service controls from a personal user profile may fix this issue. ...
Method 2: Delete Log Files. ...
Method 3: Reinstall the Service.

Comment: are you sure problem 1067 from mongodb, IThe error you mentioned, "Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly," is related to MySQL rather than MongoDB. It seems that there was a confusion or misunderstanding in the context of the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.